# asyncData hook when hard refreshing in Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, asyncdata

I just realized that the asyncData hook is not called when hard refreshing the page. But I have important data to load to show on that page. And I want to make sure that they are always available, even when the user hard refreshes the page.

Answer (score 0):

`asyncData` [from the documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/data-fetching#async-data)

> the promise returned by the asyncData hook is resolved during route transition

In that case, the best way is to use the `fetch()` hook and display a loader while you do finish your calls thanks to the `$fetchState.pending` helper.

Actually, I do think that `fetch()` is better in many ways.

Quick article on the subject: https://nuxtjs.org/blog/understanding-how-fetch-works-in-nuxt-2-12/
The one on the bottom of the page (Sergey's) is cool with some practical example of a nice implementation too.

---

You could also use this somewhat hacky solution in a layout to see if the initial location (the one you are when you hard refresh) is the one you want to be. Basically, if you land on a specific page (hard refresh or following a new window page for example) but want to have some custom behavior.

```js
beforeCreate() {
  if (!['some-other-page'].includes(this.$router.history._startLocation)) {
    this.$router.replace({ name: 'index' }).catch(() => {})
  }
},
```

Still, this one infinite loops if used in a middleware (or I made a mistake) and it's less clean than a `fetch()` hook.